# Windows 11 cannot connect to network shares (SMB) on my NAS

Tags: networking, network-shares, nas, windows-11

For a few weeks, I cannot connect anymore from my Windows 11 PC to shared folders on my Synology NAS.

The PC and the NAS are both on the same network, with static IPs. I can ping and traceroute to the NAS from the PC.

Other devices on my network can access the NAS shares like my media player (Librelec/Kodi) and even my smartphone.

The error message is

```
net use * \\DS418\Download
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

I have tried suggestions on several pages for this error message but nothing worked.

For instance, disabling IP Network Translation in the Device Manager but I don't have a "Non plug-and-play drivers" category.

The only change I made recently was on my router (Linksys WRT3200ACM). I reinstalled OpenWRT from scratch on it since I had a problem after a OpenWRT upgrade. But I see nothing in OpenWRT blocking SMB. From the PC, I can telnet to the NAS on ports 139 and 445, and I get a connection.

Everything else works fine on the PC: Wifi, Internet, connecting to the NAS admin interface, to the OpenWRT Luci interface, SSH to other servers, ...

Any clue about what I missed?

Comment: Can you connect to the NAS over SMB *using the IP address?* You're trying to guess the problem from two large and independent functions (the hostname lookup vs the actual SMB connection), you need to narrow it down to just one.

Comment: my first guess is that the NAS is set to use SMBv1 only. many linux embedded devices like phones and firesticks won't work with SMBv2/3, but windows no longer supports SMBv1 out of box.

Comment: Same error with the IP address.
The NAS is set up with SMB v2 and v3. Suspecting this too, I installed the support from SMBv1 in Windows (using optional features) but it doesn't help.